# Use drop duplicates in Pandas DF but choose keep column based on a preference list

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have dataframe with many columns. There is a datetime column, and there are duplicated entries for the datetime with data for those duplicates coming from different sources. I would like to drop the duplicates based on `column "dt"`, but I want to keep the result based on what is in `column "pref"`. I have provided simplified data below, but the reason for this is that I also have a value column, and the `"Pref"` column is the data source. I prefer certain data sources, but I only need one entry per date `(column "dt")`. I would like this code to work so that I don't have to provide a complete list of preferences either.

**Artificial Data Code**

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

 df=pd.DataFrame({'dt':[1,1,1,2,2,3,3,4,4,5],
        "Pref":[1,2,3,2,3,1,3,1,2,3],
        "Value":np.random.normal(size=10),
        "String_col":['A']*10})
df

Out[1]: 
   dt  Pref     Value  String_col
0   1     1 -0.479593  A
1   1     2  0.553963  A
2   1     3  0.194266  A
3   2     2  0.598814  A
4   2     3 -0.909138  A
5   3     1 -0.297539  A
6   3     3 -1.100855  A
7   4     1  0.747354  A
8   4     2  1.002964  A
9   5     3  0.301373  A
```

**Desired Output 1 (CASE 1):**

In this case I my preference list matters all the way down. I prefer data source 2 the most, followed by 1, but will take 3 if that is all I have.

```
preference_list=[2,1,3]

Out[2]: 
   dt  Pref     Value  String_col
1   1     2  0.553963  A
3   2     2  0.598814  A
5   3     1 -0.297539  A
8   4     2  1.002964  A
9   5     3  0.301373  A
```

**Desired Output 2 (CASE 2)**

In this case I just want to look for data source 1. If it is not present I don't actually care what the other data source is.

```
preference_list2=[1]

Out[3]: 
   dt  Pref     Value  String_col
0   1     1 -0.479593  A
3   2     2  0.598814  A
5   3     1 -0.297539  A
7   4     1  0.747354  A
9   5     3  0.301373  A
```

I can imagine doing this in a really slow and complicated loop, but I feel like there should be a command to accomplish this. **Another important thing:** I need to keep some other text columns in the data frame so .agg may cause issue for those metadata. I have experimented with sorting and using the `keep` argument in `drop_duplicates`, but with no success.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are actually looking for sorting by category, which can be done by [`pd.Categorical`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Categorical.html):

```
df["Pref"] = pd.Categorical(df["Pref"], categories=preference_list, ordered=True)

print (df.sort_values(["dt","Pref"]).drop_duplicates("dt"))

   dt Pref     Value String_col
1   1    2 -1.004362          A
3   2    2 -1.316961          A
5   3    1  0.513618          A
8   4    2 -1.859514          A
9   5    3  1.199374          A
```

Comment: This is exactly the solution I need. I was hoping to do it in one or two lines, and efficiently.

Answer (score 0):

here is a very efficient and simple solution, I hope it helps !

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


df=pd.DataFrame({'dt':[1,1,1,2,2,3,3,4,4,5],
        "Pref":[1,2,3,2,3,1,3,1,2,3],
        "Value":np.random.normal(size=10),
        "String_col":['A']*10})

preference_list = [2,3]

df_clean = df[df['Pref'].isin(preference_list)]
print(df)
print(df_clean)

Output:
  dt  Pref     Value String_col
0   1     1  1.404505          A
1   1     2  0.840923          A
2   1     3 -1.509667          A
3   2     2 -1.431240          A
4   2     3 -0.576142          A
5   3     1 -1.208514          A
6   3     3 -0.456773          A
7   4     1  0.574463          A
8   4     2 -1.682750          A
9   5     3  0.719394          A
   dt  Pref     Value String_col
1   1     2  0.840923          A
2   1     3 -1.509667          A
3   2     2 -1.431240          A
4   2     3 -0.576142          A
6   3     3 -0.456773          A
8   4     2 -1.682750          A
9   5     3  0.719394          A
```

Comment: Hi Andres. I appreciate the answer but that doesn't actually give the desired output, if you look above. This would be useful in certain cases, but I want one and only one entry for each dt. You get duplicates of the first and second dt.